# iphone app facebook newsfeed list control

Tags: iphone, facebook, list

Im just wondering what is the most appropriate control and approach to creating a similar list control to the facebook newsfeed list?

Each entry in the list will contain an image, some formatted text and in some cases a hyperlink to another page in the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably looking for a UITableView, with custom UITableViewCells.  Should be pretty straight forward.